# Dynamically update Apache config "allow from IP" without a restart/reload?

Tags: apache, restart

My goal is to allow access to an Apache 2.2 forwarding proxy to the IPs of logged-in users only, while denying all other IPs.

In the proxy virtual host, I've successfully included an "allow from" file that gets dynamically rewritten every time a user logs in or out of the site (adding the IP of logged-in users while deleting the IP of logged-out users).  However, this requires a graceful restart/reload of Apache to take effect, and I'm looking to improve the performance if I can... because as the user logs in and is transported to the main page, occasionally Apache is right in the middle of the restart and issues a "busy" warning.

I suppose that I could delay the graceful restart of Apache by a second or two to ease the stress on the initial log-in, but if there is a way to avoid the restart altogether, I'd really appreciate knowing about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

> However, this requires a graceful
>   restart/reload of Apache to take
>   effect,

Please do not do this. This is not a solution.

Use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) directive from Apache's mod_rewrite (RewriteModule) to achieve a dynamic file based IP blacklisting/white listing.

```
## WHITELIST IPS ##
RewriteMap ipslist txt:/path/to/whitelist.txt
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${ipslist:%1|black} ^black$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

Comment: +1 effectively the rewriteMap cache is flushed when the mtime of the file change.

Comment: +1 great answer, but can I replace whitelist.txt with a DB. @Sarwar Erfan

Comment: @Nidal, yes.  Just change txt: to dbm: or any of the other types listed in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap