# Dynamic whitelist with htaccess allowing a form to add an IP to the whitelist?

Tags: php, .htaccess, lamp

Working on a dev site for a client, we want to deny all access from it, but allow easy whitelisting when out of office for meetings or working from home (dynamic ip).

What we want to happen, is have a form, that writes your IP address to the htaccess file along with a comment above it stating who this is or who authorized it etc.

Without going into a bunch of details, a simple password wont work in our case, having people monitor email accounts for requests, having clients obtain their own IP addresses, things like this just wont fly.

What would be nice, is allowing these added IP addresses in htaccess to expire. So I figure complicated logic like that wont fly in htaccess itself, so it would need to be managed by a 3rd party software, unless anyone has any other ideas?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676954/dynamically-update-apache-config-allow-from-ip-without-a-restart-reload

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Wish there was a usage example though, lol. I am looking into it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using Apache's RewriteMap directive. Please note that to use the RewriteMap directive you have to place the directive in the httpd.conf and NOT the .htaccess file. You can use it in several simple ways.

### Plain text file

The plain text version allows you to have a .txt file that holds the ip addresses.  I added a line for a comment.  This way doesn't allow auto expiration.

**httpd.conf**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap ipmap txt:/path/to/whitelist.txt

RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !^allow$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

**whitelist.txt**

```
# Chris London added this 2013/06/14
127.0.0.1 allow
123.45.67.89 allow # Some other comment
```

### Custom Program

With the RewriteMap you can actually have it run an external program but this one comes with some caveats.  I personally haven't used this method especially with a PHP script.  To make it work with a PHP script, I believe, it has to run indefinitely reading the stdin and writing to the stdout.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLock /path/to/rewrite.lock
Rewritemap ipmap prg:/path/to/executable.php

RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !^allow$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

**executable.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$in = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$out = fopen('php://stdout', 'r');

while ($ip = fgets($f)) {
    // TODO add better logic
    if ($ip == '127.0.0.1') {
        fwrite(out, 'allow');
    } else {
        fwrite(out, 'deny');
    }
}

fclose($f);
```

- Keep your rewrite map program as simple as possible. If the program hangs, it will cause httpd to wait indefinitely for a response from the map, which will, in turn, cause httpd to stop responding to requests.
- Be sure to turn off buffering in your program. Buffered I/O will cause httpd to wait for the output, and so it will hang.
- Remember that there is only one copy of the program, started at server startup. All requests will need to go through this one bottleneck. This can cause significant slowdowns if many requests must go through this process, or if the script itself is very slow.

### DB Query

I also haven't used this one yet but it looks pretty neat. mod_dbd will need to be configured to point at the right database for this to work.  You have a SQL statement that fetchs the ip addresses and you can add a filter for the expiration date.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap ipmap "dbd:SELECT ipaddress FROM rewrite WHERE expiration < TIME() and ipaddress = %s"

RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !^%{REMOTE_ADDR}$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

There are a couple other types out there but these seem to be the best fit for you.  Like I said before I haven't used the Custom Program or the DB Query before so I may have said something wrong. Hopefully another user on here may catch my mistake so these will all work for you.

Comment: I am trying the flat file variation, yet its spitting out a 500 error. I tried adjusting the path, but no avail.

Comment: I forgot to mention and I will put this in my post. You can't add RewriteMap to the .htaccess file. You have to add them to the httpd.conf for Apache

Comment: Does that preclude this from being used on a single domain/site within an installation? There are some sites we don't want this list to apply to.

Comment: Usually each site is in a <VirtualHost> record and you can place these rules in the <VirtualHost> record for the particular site

Comment: I have a question @chrislondon. what method do you prefer the most to allow/disallow ip addresses and is better in terms of efficiency. keeping in mind the allow/disallow ip addresses can be added/removed on daily basis.

Comment: @thesaadarshad I've never used this in a production environment.  I would guess the DB Query method would be your best bet.  If you try it let me know how well it works for you.