# httacces allow only my domain

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to allow only my IP but my IP needs to be read from my url or somehow else.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444   <- needs to be dynamic, not actual typed number
```

Comment: I don't think that it can be dynamic. Maybe you should consider to use htpasswd instead?

Comment: There is a good suggestion here (use a file to manage whitelisted IP's): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108254/dynamic-whitelist-with-htaccess-allowing-a-form-to-add-an-ip-to-the-whitelist

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Comment: I need deny from all but iframe that pulls iframe under the same domain. Is that possible?

Comment: not exactly dynamic, but you [can specify ip ranges in `.htaccess`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042399/htaccess-access-to-file-by-ip-range)

Comment: I don't think I'm asking right question. This isn't going to work for me.